# Compared nested arrays with mongo

Tags: mongodb

I need to compare two nested arrays with mongo but I'm not really an expert so I need some help on doing that.

Let's say I have a document with an array `slots`:

```
[
    [
        {
            "start": 1,
            "end": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "start": 3,
            "end": 4
        },
        {
            "start": 5,
            "end": 6
        }
    ]
]
```

And I need to know if another array is a subset of it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      slots: {
        $setIsSubset: [
          [
            [
              {
                start: 1,
                end: 2
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                start: 3,
                end: 4
              },
              {
                start: 5,
                end: 6
              }
            ]
          ],
          "$slots"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This returns true, but if I remove one element in the second sub array, it returns false as the sub array isn't equal anymore.

I thought of doing some kind of `$map` where I would compare each sub array but I realized I didn't know how to reference the index of the array we're comparing to.

Any ideas? Thanks

Edit : the first level of the stored array and the array we're comparing it with are days of the week so that information needs to be kept.

[Online sandbox](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ubO1AfECnOG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider those nested arrays as days of week you probably need to compare them day by day and check if all "pairs" are subsets. To achieve that you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to add your input as another field and then in the next step run [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/index.html) on every day based on index generated by [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) operator. If all elements are true ([$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/index.html)) then it means that you specified a subset for every day:

```
var input = [
    [
        {
        start: 1,
        end: 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
        start: 5,
        end: 6
        }
    ]
];

db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            inputArray: input
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            isSubset: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$slots" } ] },
                        as: "index",
                        in: {
                            $setIsSubset: [
                                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$inputArray", "$$index" ] },
                                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$slots", "$$index" ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I can't extract the arrays as their position is significant (it refers to a day of the week). I'll edit the OP.

Comment: @MrVoodoo so maybe you could keep `slots` as the original array but run `$setIsSubset` on flattened array just to check if subsets match ?

Comment: In some cases the check would pass even if it shouldn't.
For example Monday has {start: 1, end: 2} and I want to check if Tuesday has {start: 1, end: 2}, it would pass the test.

Comment: @MrVoodoo I see, modfied my answer

Comment: Very nice. I'll try that and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. Now I know how to access specific elements with $map :)

Comment: Hi @mickl Did you get anything from stackoverflow after hitting 10k or 15k?

Comment: Hi @AnthonyWinzlet what do you mean by "anything" ? All I know is that you get priviledges like "Protect questions" when you hit 15k. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Nopes I meant something like "hamper" or "gift hamper"?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet it would be nice but I'm not aware of any gifts like that. Why are you asking about that ? Is there any page which says that we should get someting like that :) ?

Comment: ***Why are you asking about that*** Actually one of my colleague has gotten two wonderful gift hampers(containing two mugs, t-shirts, bottles and much more) from the stackoverflow. She has participated in some contest on the stackoverflow I don't know much about that but she has. I read about that on metaexchange and learned that SO rewards that on 100k reps but she has only 1k. So I wanted to know whether I m missing something. BTW Thank you